# how to run monerod as service on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: monerod, daemon

I've installed monerod on remote ubuntu machine, but can't start as daemon.
systemd service keeps failing.

tried to run with --detach with no luck.

> systemd[1]: Starting Monero Full Node...
>
> systemd[1]: monerod.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
>
> systemd[1]: Failed to start Monero Full Node.
>
> systemd[1]: monerod.service: Unit entered failed state.
>
> systemd[1]: monerod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

can anybody share experience with running monerod as systemd service?

Comment: Did you use the monerod.service file which comes with monero (utils/systemd/monerod.service) ? If not, you probably need "GuessMainPID=no"

Comment: yes, I'm using exactly same config file only user/group is changed

Answer (score -1):

use the flag --non-interactive